# Border left for 3 cells on each other

Tags: html

I'm using HTML tables to draw a table which has a border left to draw a line in the centre of a 3 x 2 table. Unfortunately there are gaps in this border where the cell starts and ends.

Can someone tell me how to get rid of this please??
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try:

<table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>